# Problems while implementing AndroidX SeekBarPreference

Tags: android, androidx, android-preferences, android-seekbar, android-settings

I'm trying to add a [SeekBarPreference](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/preference/SeekBarPreference) to my [Android Settings](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings) PreferenceScreen.
Everything works when I use an EditTextPreference for example, so it's definitely the SeekBar which is causing problems.

First problem: I can specify a min value with `app:min=""`, but `app:max=""` doesn't seem to exist.. I guess it's a bug in the API, because I found this statement in the docs:

> Other SeekBar specific attributes (e.g. title, summary, defaultValue, min, max) can be set directly on the preference widget layout.

Second problem: When I use the code below, my app crashes with the following message when opening the settings: `Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`

My code:

```
public class PreferenceFragment extends PreferenceFragmentCompat {

    @Override
    public void onCreatePreferences(Bundle savedInstanceState, String rootKey) {
        setPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.settings, rootKey);
    }
}
```

and

```
<PreferenceScreen xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <PreferenceCategory
        app:key="category_playback"
        app:title="Playback">

        <SeekBarPreference
            app:defaultValue="15"
            app:key="skip_time"
            app:min="5"
            app:summary="Seconds to skip"
            app:title="Skip time" />

    </PreferenceCategory>

</PreferenceScreen>
```

Anyone got an idea on how to fix it? If there's no solution I will try to implement it programmatically.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you find a fix for the 2nd problem ? How ?

Comment: After clearing the app data it worked again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For your **first problem** use:

```
android:max="10"
```

For your **second problem**, try clearing your app data.

Comment: Thanks after clearing the app data it works. It's still weird though that the app:max attribute doesn't exist.